# Herbert Dingle's paradox modified

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames

Suppose two spaceships A and B have on them clocks A and B move along the same straight line at uniform speeds differing by 161 miles per second. And suppose they are at positions A and B in space when both clocks say noon. And suppose that after noon, they are set to collide with one another when clock A says 2 o'clock.

My question is what time will clock B say when the two spaceships collide? By symmetry, the answer should be 2 o'clock. However, according to special relativity, the answer is 1 o'clock. Which answer is right? They can't both be right.

This is a modification of a paradox found in Herbert Dingle's book *Science at the Crossroads*.

Comment: "...and are at positions A and B in space when both clocks say noon".  According to whom?

Comment: there a long rod, that moves at the same speed relative to both whose ends are a and b, and both spaceships get there in such a way that when A sees itself in a, it sees that B is at  b, and viceverza. At that moment both reset their clocks to noon

Comment: or is that impossible and I am missing something?

Comment: @bruce You are missing something. The ships do not agree on the assertion of simultaneity. Their time axes are not parallel and if they both arrive at their designated points at noon in ship A's frame, then they *don't* do so in ship B's frame. If they arrive at the designated points at noon is the rods POV then they don't do so in either ship's frame *and* each ship asserts a different ordering (A arrives first versus B arrives first).

Comment: @dmckee Thanks, but I' m still missing something. You agree that when ship A reaches a it can be possible for it to see B reaching b at the same time.  They are moving with the same relative speed (but opposite directions ) relative to the rod. Should not by symmetry B see A reaching a when B reaches b?     Will B see A reach a before or after it sees itself at b? and why?

Comment: Please read these articles and decide if you want to pursue anything that Dingle has said about Special Relativity.  http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath024/kmath024.htm and http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath317/kmath317.htm

Comment: You need to clarify the question.  Which direction are the spaceships moving?  Collinear?  If so, are they moving toward each other or is one gaining on the other?  Is it really their speeds that differ by that amount, or their velocities?  Why did you choose the speed "161,000 miles per second," which is neither in SI units, nor in the units of time you already used earlier in the problem, nor a nice fraction of the speed of light?

Comment: I clarified the question. I chose 161,000 miles per second because sqrt(1-(161 miles per second)^2/c^2) is approximately 1/2.

Comment: Are they moving toward each other or in the same direction?

Comment: Also, I think everyone would be happier if you just said that the speed was $(\sqrt{3}/2) c$.

Comment: @tparker Dingle used 161,000 miles per second.

Comment: @tparker They are both headed towards one another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean by their clocks both being at noon when they're at positions A and B, and their speeds differing by 161,000 miles per second. By the way the question was stated, I'll assume you meant their positions were measured *in an outside observer's frame*, i.e., at noon in the outside observer's frame ship A is at position A and ship B is at position B. We can also assume ship A sync's up its *own* clock to read noon when it's at point A, and similarly for ship B. (It is impossible for both ships to see both clocks at noon at once. If ship A sees both clocks at noon at one time, then ship B won't, and vice versa. Specifically, if ship A sees the event of itself being at point A (with its clock at noon) coincide with the event of ship B being at point B (with *its* clock at noon), then ship B will not see these events coincide.)

As for what frame their relative speeds are measured in, it sounds like you meant the ships' frames, i.e. ship A sees ship B moving towards it at 161,000 miles per second, and ship B sees ship A moving towards it at 161,000 miles per second. Then the $\gamma$ factor between the two frames is about $2$, meaning time *appears* to move half as fast for one ship as measured from the other. Unfortunately, having specified their relative speed in their own frames doesn't specify it in the outside observer's frame. This is what matters, since the outside observer's frame is the frame in which both their clocks were seen reading noon at once.

If one ship is moving faster than the other in this frame (the outside observer's frame), then its clock will elapse less time than the other's.

Comment: Thank you, my rustiness with this subject is what caused me to make the mistake. I didn't account for the fact that the noon times are not really synchronized.